# How to use Google Analytics for Goals on Email Sign up page?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single webpage that allows users to signup for a Mail Chimp Newsletter. When they sign up, they are taken to a custom "thank you" page.

I want to use Google Analytics to track how many people make it to the "thank you" page, so I can test the usability of my sign up page.

I thought a Google Analytic Goal would be perfect for this, using a "destination Goal".

My settings are as follows:

Property Settings URL: `books.madhu.co/signup/aaromance/aaromance1-iyb/`

Goal Destination URL: `regular expression Equal to "/thanks.html"`

Despite this, it doesn't seem to track any of the people who reach the "thank you" page.

The URL of my sign up page is: http://books.madhu.co/signup/aaromance/aaromance1-iyb/index.html

The URL of my thank you page is: 
http://books.madhu.co/signup/aaromance/aaromance1-iyb/thanks.html

I have checked the source code carefully and the Google Anlytics code is on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if Google Analytics regular expression searches whole string or assumes start of string matching.

If it's the later (which I suspect it is) then you should have the following:

Goal Destination URL: regular expression Equal to "/signup/aaromance/aaromance1-iyb/thanks.html"

Or:

Goal Destination URL: regular expression Equal to ".*/thanks.html"

I understand you have the property settings URL set to that first bit [but don't think that affects the page view tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628633/in-google-analytics-property-settings-what-difference-does-the-default-url-make). Though this is easily verified either by making above change and verifying the goal or by looking under behaviour to see what this page view is tracked as.