# How to use Google analytics for injected scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I wrote some Js scripts that others can put on their websites. I want to use Google Analytics to track its usage. There are many articles talking about how to inject `GA.js`, but I'm asking how to create property on Google Analytics' admin page:
[image]

What **"Website URL"** should I fill in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In google analytics property settings, what difference does the Default URL makes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628633/in-google-analytics-property-settings-what-difference-does-the-default-url-make)

Comment: @EikePierstorff no it's not.

Comment: It answers exactly your question, in my book that makes it a duplicate (although I admit the name of the field changed, but it's still the same answer).

Comment: @EikePierstorff So I could fill whatever url like `abc.com`?

Comment: Yes. It makes no difference at all for data collection (which makes sense, else e.g. you couldn't do cross domain tracking if you were limited to a single domain).